What is the purpose of the following function - tree structure
i had a test and i need to find out what is the purpose of the next code:
typedef struct _node* Nodeptr;
typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    Nodeptr left;
    Nodeptr right;
} Node;

int F(Nodeptr root, int value) {
    int tmp;

    if (root == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        tmp = root->data;
        root->data = value;
        return tmp;
    }

    root->data = F(root->left, root->data);

    return F(root->right, value);
}

where you call F(root,root->data)
what is the purpose of the code?
my idea was that the code change the node values in a similar order to InOrderTraversal, but i think its not accurate.

Welcome to SO. Didn't you get the solutions after your test?

actually not .
furthermore in the second test this question appeared again.

If that was a test, you need to learn how it works. Therefore you should do 2 things: 1) Draw a tree with some random values and execute the function with pen&paper. How will the recursive calls work? What values are moved/swapped in that process? 2) Build a program that creates a sample tree (maybe the same as with your pen&paper version) and execute the function step by step. If you then find a difference between 1) and 2) you should address that in your question.

"where you call F(root,root->value)": that will not compile. root->value is not a valid expression. Did you maybe mean root->data?

The result of the code does not really fit a nice description. I wonder if it really does what the askers intended to. If the binary tree is a full binary tree, then every interior node's value is swapped with the value of its predecessor node (i.e. the rightmost node in its left subtree). But the rightmost node (of all) will get the root's value, which becomes duplicated, while that rightmost value is lost. If the binary tree is not of the full type, then -1 will occur here and there when the node has no left subtree to find the predecessor in... this really makes it a mess in my opinion.

[...] This is just a rough description as the mess is greater than that. If an interior node has a predecessor that is not a leaf, it will also get -1 as a value (its original value is lost). I'm at a loss why this is an exam question. I cannot see a useful purpose in this code. Sure, it deterministically does something that can be described, but nothing that seems useful. If the question would specify that the tree is a non-empty, full binary tree, it would improve the situation though. Also it would make more sense if the calling code would assign the returned value to root->data.

I very much agree with you. It made me rack my brain for a long time in the test. I thought maybe I was wrong and missing something. But can't find any answer in any source. The code just seems to have no meaningful purpose.

This is what the code achieves:

Every leaf that has a successor node gets its value swapped with that of its successor node. The successor node of a leaf is the closest node that has that leaf in its left subtree.

If there is a leaf without successor node, then its value is set to whatever value was passed as second argument in the top-level call of the function, and the original value of that leaf is returned by that function call. If there is no such leaf (that has no successor node), then the top-level call of the function returns -1.

Any node that didn't get its value updated by the above two mechanisms, receives the value -1. These are internal nodes that don't have a leaf as predecessor node.


In my humble opinion this seems a strange outcome for a function, and I cannot see how it could be useful: some values are swapped, other values are lost, and if the top-level function passes as second argument root->data as you have indicated, then this value could occur twice in the updated tree. I wonder if this is what the designers of this test really had in mind, or whether they had intended something else.
